# What techniques or functions can help manage hundreds of buffers?

Tags: buffers

After several months of work, my Emacs easily accumulates 400 or 500 buffers.  This makes restoring from `desktop-mode` irritatingly slow.  I'd love to be able to delete buffers in bulk, ideally from the buffer list.  For example, "mark for deletion every buffer associated with a file whose name matches regexp" or similar.  But I can't find such a function, and looking at the way the buffer list is implemented, I can't figure out how to write one myself.

What functions or techniques exist for managing a large number of buffers?

Comment: You can also use midnight mode which will kill buffers that have not been looked at for a given time e.g. 3 days and that don't need to be saved. But emacs needs to be open for all the time not restarted from desktop-save

Comment: The question isn't a good fit for emacs.SE. It's too open-ended, not well defined, and encourages opinion-based answers. Questions that are specific how-to are good fits.

Comment: See the similar question linked above. The example there is Ibuffer's `% m` which marks by mode, but there is also `% f` which marks by (displayed) `buffer-file-name`, as well as many other bells and whistles.

Comment: @Basil if you'd care to write an answer involving `ibuffer` I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @NormanRamsey I was in the middle of doing so, but then I realised I was mostly duplicating Phil's answer to the question that this one is marked as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2):

I would activate electric-buffer-list and apply this small function :

```
(defun buffer-list-mark-for-deleting (rxp)
  "Mark all *Buffer Lines* lines matching the regexp RXP for deleting"
  (interactive  "sRegexp to delete : " )
  (with-current-buffer "*Buffer List*"
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward-regexp rxp nil t)
      (Buffer-menu-delete))))
```

For instance, the regexp "^ +* *[hH]elm" will mark all entry beginning with " * helm" or " * Helm" with the "D" letter. Selecting any non mark buffer will delete the marked ones.

You can build much more complex regexps using re-builder and write some specific functions for your needs.

Of course, you can bind this function to a key sequence according to your desire.